# Creating image with dynamic value with PHP

Tags: php, bitcoin

I want to create a small function in PHP which takes in a curled value and outputs it as an image. I read through PHP Image Processing and GD but I seem to have a logical error somewhere, as all i get is a blank image although i am getting the value without problems.
Does anybody see where i went wrong?

```
<?php
// Dynamic value on an image 
header("Content-type: image/png");

// Get value from API.
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json',
'Content-Type:  application/json'));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/');

$data = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

$obj = json_decode($data);

$price = round((40/($obj->{'last'})),3);
$image = imagecreatefrompng("price.png");
$color = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 255);

// Calculate horizontal alignment for the value.
$BoundingBox1 = imagettfbbox(13, 0, 'ITCKRIST.TTF', $price);
$boyX = ceil((125 - $BoundingBox1[2]) / 2);

// Write value.
imagettftext($image, 13, 0, $boyX+25, 92, $color, 'ITCKRIST.TTF', $price);

// Return output.
ImageJPEG($image, NULL, 93);
ImageDestroy($image);
?>
```

Comment: Did you install the font on the server?

Answer (score 0):

## You have mismatched the content-type, and your data.

You are hinting that your image file is a PNG

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
```

But you output a JPEG

```
ImageJPEG($image, NULL, 93);
```

## Also regarding your font file

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename along a library-defined font path.

Quote From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

#### Below is working code that actually worked properly on my server

```
<?php

// Dynamic value on an image 
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$data = file_get_contents('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/', false, $context);
$obj = json_decode($data);

$price = round((40/($obj->{'last'})),3);
$image = imagecreatefrompng("price.png");
$color = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 255);

// Calculate horizontal alignment for the value.
$BoundingBox1 = imagettfbbox(13, 0, './ITCKrist.TTF', $price);
$boyX = ceil((125 - $BoundingBox1[2]) / 2);

// Write value.
imagettftext($image, 13, 0, $boyX+25, 92, $color, './ITCKrist.TTF', $price);

// Return output.
ImageJPEG($image, NULL, 93);
ImageDestroy($image);
?>
```